# Kerberos SSO with weblogic

Tags: apache, weblogic, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have managed to configure the weblogic for the SSO with windows AD, however there are several questions on which I need clarity

1) When I access the application from my browser with the apache web server sitting in between, why is the weblogic requesting for a TGT with the SPN everytime(I can see that in weblogic console), even if it wants to get authenticated with the KDC this should have happened only once during start up and not with every request from same browser.

Theoretically Weblogic should never contact the KDC to validate the existing user's TGT.

2) If the same session key provided by the KDC is used between client and weblogic server for secure communication, they would never require to hit KDC in between unless the session key expires, in which case they also have an option to renew it, so a TGT is never required to be created for each request from browser to weblogic. Is it correct.

Weblogic console logs->

```
Found ticket for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM to go to krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM expiring on Fri May 11 21:06:46 CDT 2018
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache true useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is http_weblogic_test.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
KinitOptions cache name is D:\Users\ayadav.DOMAIN.000\krb5cc_ayadav
Acquire default native Credentials
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 23.
LSA contains TGT for ayadav@DOMAIN.COM not HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Principal is HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
null credentials from Ticket Cache
Looking for keys for: HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Added key: 17version: 14
Added key: 18version: 14
Added key: 23version: 14
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Looking for keys for: HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Added key: 17version: 14
Added key: 18version: 14
Added key: 23version: 14
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 23.
KrbAsReq creating message
KrbKdcReq send: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=163
KDCCommunication: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=163
KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=207
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 19
PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 17, salt = DOMAIN.COMHTTPAPPDEV2011.domain.com, s2kparams = null
PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 2
PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 16
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 15
KdcAccessibility: remove wcosp-dc01.domain.com
KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
KRBError:
sTime is Fri May 11 11:06:46 CDT 2018 1526054806000
suSec is 633784
error code is 25
error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
sname is krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
eData provided.
msgType is 30
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 19
PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 17, salt = DOMAIN.COMHTTPAPPDEV2011.domain.com, s2kparams = null
PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 2
PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 16
Pre-Authentication Data:
PA-DATA type = 15
KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 23.
Looking for keys for: HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Added key: 17version: 14
Added key: 18version: 14
Added key: 23version: 14
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Looking for keys for: HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Added key: 17version: 14
Added key: 18version: 14
Added key: 23version: 14
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 23.
EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
KrbAsReq creating message
KrbKdcReq send: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=250
KDCCommunication: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=250
KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=96
KrbKdcReq send: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=250
KDCCommunication: kdc=wcosp-dc01.domain.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=250
DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1602 bytes
KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1602
KdcAccessibility: remove wcosp-dc01.domain.com
Looking for keys for: HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Added key: 17version: 14
Added key: 18version: 14
Added key: 23version: 14
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com
principal is HTTP/APPDEV2011.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded 
>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an Apache web server in between?  Weblogic comes with it's own web server.

Comment: Yes ,but for performance reasons we need to have static resources available with the apache server only, this mechanism prevents the weblogic to become overwhelmed and also give us an opportunity to configure the redirects independently.